# How to detect when Return is pressed in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have an application with a UITextField and I would like to trigger a method in my view controller when the user has entered a line of text. The EditingDidEnd event is not triggered until the keyboard is dismissed and the Editing Changed event fires on every key up. Is there an event fired when the user presses Return? It seems like I have seen this behavior in first-party apps.

Answer (score 9):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```